# DateTime returns wrong date

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to get today's date

```
DateTime todayDateTime = new DateTime();
```

and I'm getting this:

```
{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Show your code as well. It is the value of [`DateTime.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) field.

Comment: DateTime todayDateTime = new DateTime();

Comment: Unlike Java's `DateTime todayDateTime = new Date()` which creates current datetime, C# returns "zero" datetime; use `DateTime todayDateTime = DateTime.Now;` in C# instead

Answer (score 18):

Use this

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: `DateTime date = DateTime.Today;` is often the better choice.

Answer (score 5):

Using  `new DateTime()` creates a DateTime with a time of "0".

If you want todays date you need to use `DateTime.Today` if you want a DateTime object with a date of today and a time of 12:00:00 AM or `DateTime.Now` if you want a DateTime with the day and time of the moment you called `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, the [constructor for DateTime which takes in a long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) initializes by using the specified number of ticks since **January 1st, 0001**, so saying `new DateTime(0)` yields this time, not the current time.

Instead, use the static field [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a **DateTime** representing the current system time.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are just initializing the Variable todayDateTime but you have never assigned (set it). This is why it is date ("null")/ beginning of our time calculations.

To actually get todays Date, you can use the following:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to assigned a value in the datetime.
just use something like this :

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```